# Unable to display Alert from an Observable Object

Tags: swiftui, alert, combine

**Scenario:** 
I want to be able to display an Alert() from an Observable Object, via  @Published values (networkMessage & hasAlert).

This alert should be fired when missing a network connection. 
via 
[image]

**Host View** that displays the Alert() :

```
import SwiftUI

struct EndPointView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var settings: Settings
    @ObservedObject var standardWeatherReport = StandardWeatherReport()
    @ObservedObject var publishedWeatherReport = PublishedWeatherReport()
    @ObservedObject var pepBoy = PepBoy()
    @ObservedObject var postMan = PostMan()

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Text("Chosen One: \(settings.endpointSection)")
            Text("Row Two")
            Text("Row Three")
            Text("Row Four")

        }.onAppear {
            self.acquireData()
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $standardWeatherReport.hasAlert, content: { () -> Alert in
            Alert(title: Text(verbatim: standardWeatherReport.networkMessage!))
        })
    }

    func acquireData() {
        let chosenEndPoint = EndPoints(rawValue: settings.endpointSection)
        switch chosenEndPoint {
            case .standardWeather:
                standardWeatherReport.doStandard()
            case .publishedWeather:
                publishedWeatherReport.doPublish()
            case .postman:
                postMan.doPublishPostMan()
            case .publishpepboy:
                pepBoy.doPublishPep()
            case .none:
                print("none")
        }
    }
}
```

**Observable Object** the initially fired off the Alert() via case .failure(let anError):

```
import Foundation

class PublishedWeatherReport: ObservableObject {
    @Published var networkMessage: String?
    @Published var hasAlert = false
    @Published var weatherReport: String?

    func doPublish() {
        let url = EndPoint.weather.path()
        var request = URLRequest(url: EndPoint.weather.path()!)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

        // Publisher:
        let remoteDataPublisher = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url!)
            // the dataTaskPublisher output combination is (data: Data, response: URLResponse)
            .map { $0.data }
            .decode(type: Sample.self, decoder: decoder)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()

        // Subscriber:
        sub = remoteDataPublisher // ...must assign to an iVar to keep alive.
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
                switch completion {
                case .finished:
                    break
                case .failure(let anError):
                    self.networkMessage = anError.localizedDescription
                    self.hasAlert = true.  // ... unable to host Alert().
                }
            }, receiveValue: { someValue in
                print(".sink() received \(someValue)")
            })
    }
}
```

**Question:** Why am I not getting this alert() via

```
(isPresented: $standardWeatherReport.hasAlert)?
```

Answer (score 0):

`standardWeatherReport.hasAlert` is not from the class `PublishedWeatherReport`.
where is the `StandardWeatherReport` class

Comment: I got multiple publishers.  The code above shows both Standard & Published Weather Reports: I got them mixed (typo); thanks for your observation.

Answer (score 0):

I got two publishers mixed.
Hence the concerned alert wasn't functioning correctly.

Also I have **multiple** alert operators, each one per publisher.

*This is a bad design:* Only one (1) alert operator is allowed per host; otherwise the second .alert operator would override the previous operator.

So if one alert is active, a following *inactive* alert operator would immediately cancel it.